# How does NMR spectrometer determine area under each peak?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

I am confused about exactly how does NMR machine figure our area under each peak, which then tells us how much protons present in the molecule. Does it have to do something with radio waves being emiitted after proton relaxes? Thanks.

Comment: It [integrates](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral).

Comment: Can u explain in terms of the energy absorbed or given of? It must integrate through some information known.

Comment: You got a curve intensity vs. frequency and you can just integrate that.

Comment: The NMR integrates the electrical current under the peak.

Comment: It's certainly not current. You have a free induction decay plot. The more protons you have of a certain type, the more they contribute to the intensity of that frequency. Once you Fourier transform the signal, you get a stronger intensity for those frequencies.

Comment: And how exactly  do you go from more intensity of frequency to having more protons? That was what I was trying to get at from my question.

Comment: @Zhe - Back when I was doing NMR the data came out on a strip chart recorder. The integration was literally done by integrating the electrical current under the peak.

Comment: @TLo You basically shock the protons into an excited state that causes them to radiate EM radiation over time. The more protons of a given kind, the more energy they can radiate...

Comment: @MaxW Ah, sorry. Old school. I've only ever used a continuous scan NMR once in 2000. 60MHz. Didn't even have to cool the magnet...

Answer (score 3):

The modern basic FT 1H NMR experiment involves irradiating and simultaneously exciting a wide bandwidth of proton frequencies. That is to say, all spin populations of the proton nuclei have their spin state reversed with a carefully calibrated Rf pulse that delivers the correct amount of power for the correct duration. As each spin relaxes back to equilibrium, it emits a photon of Rf energy. So, yes your assumption is pretty well correct. This energy packet has a specific frequency (a product of the chemical shift), and a specific intensity - it is a quantum packet of energy. If two nuclei of the same frequency each emit a photon of energy, the intensity of that frequency detected will be twice as large a single nucleus emitting a photon of energy.

Across the entire frequency range, the data collected in the free induction decay is the sum product of all frequencies,  *and their intensities*. The Fourier transform function then converts this time domain data into the preferred frequency domain spectrum.